# Panning DIV element around using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I am trying to have a div in a container which when the user clicks and drags somewhere in the document area, the .room element pans around inside the .viewport element by holding down the middle click button.

Here is the issue: (Hold right click for this one, middle click didn't work for some reason)
http://jsfiddle.net/JeZj5/2/

JS

```
var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;
var scale = 1.0;

$(document).mousemove(function (e) {

    var offset = $('.room').offset();

    //relative mouse x,y
    mouseX = parseFloat((e.pageX - offset.left) / scale, 2);
    mouseY = parseFloat((e.pageY - offset.top) / scale, 2);

    //absolute mouse x,y
    mouseXRaw = e.pageX;
    mouseYRaw = e.pageY;

    $(".room").html(mouseX + ', ' + mouseY + '<br />Right click document and pan');

    switch (e.which) {
        case 3:
            $('.room').css({
                left: mouseX,
                top: mouseY
            });
            break;
    }
    return true;
});

$(document).on('contextmenu', function () {
    return false;
});
```

Comment: You should watch the mousedown event and then track movement instead of watching all the mouse movement and then seeing if the mouse is down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be more along the lines of what you're looking for.  Key change:

```
delta.x = e.pageX - drag.x;
delta.y = e.pageY - drag.y;
```

Using the delta to change the position.  The `.room`'s position should be moving with respect to it's current location, minus the mouse drag position (not the other way around).

http://jsfiddle.net/X2PZP/3/

Comment: It does work as I need it to, however, if there's elements inside the .room div then clicking and dragging won't work.

Comment: Plus, for some reason it disabled my text inputs.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your first comment.  Could you give me an example?  I updated the fiddle with the text back in, and made it use the **middle** mouse button like you originally intended.

Comment: Removing the return false; from your mousedown event fixes the disabled text input. And about the elements, I did handle another mousedown event, so just adding e.which == 1 to that, fixed it as they won't handle ALL mouse button events now. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out.  All the best!

Comment: improved the code from @AlexanderMistakidis by adding inertia. check and have fun: http://jsfiddle.net/X2PZP/47/